# Get application mouse events without capture?

Tags: .net, wpf, mouseevent

I want to make a user control like this:

If the `TextBox` gets focus, a `PopUp` is shown; if the `TextBox` loses focus, the `PopUp` is hidden. That's not difficult. However, here is another requirement:

If the user click (mouse down) on the other areas/elements(Neither on the TextBox nor the `PopUp`) of this window, the PopUp is supposed to hide. (Notice: the focus is still on the `TextBox`):

[image]

And there are many reasons not to capture the mouse for the `TextBox`, the most important one is the `TextBox` has its own mechanism to handle the mouse event. Capturing the mouse may make the `TextBox` behaviours odd.

I am wondering if there is a method to get the application mouse events without capture the mouse?

I think there must be, think about the `ComboBox`, you know what I mean.

[image]

Comment: There is a related discussion here, but it's not very helpful to me. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b699d4df-fbf0-4e47-9e4b-86b5f7865f68/

Comment: Handle common window click event, find if it is out of bound of Combobox using HitTest, and do the proper handling.